# Delete Joomla article generic icon

Tags: joomla1.5

I am happily using joomla but I can't find in any menu the function to delete generic article icon so I've changed it with a small one made of a single white pixel in png.
The effect is not lovely (you see a little space before the article title: www.aich-neuromed.it)...
How can I get rid of article icon in joomla?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you will need to change 2 lines of CSS in template.css

First, near line 384 romove the left padding for the headlines, you wont need it any more:

```
table.contentpaneopen td.contentheading {
padding-left: 34px;
}
```

You can just delete the whole thing.

Next, near line 376 you will need to remove the background image part of the CSS:

```
background: url(../images/contentheading_ico.png) left top no-repeat;
```

That should take care of it.